# I can't run my react native code even though I have an emulator running in the back round

Tags: javascript, react-native, android-emulator

I am trying to run react native code but when I use react-native run-android I get this error message.  I am using android studio.

```
~/Downloads/BrainG-master$ sudo react-native run-android

Scanning folders for symlinks in /home/luke/Downloads/BrainG-
master/node_modules (10ms)

JS server already running.

Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew 
installDebug)...

: No such file or directory

Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for 
details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected 
and have
set up your Android development environment:
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure

1. there is an `android` directory inside `/Downloads/BrainG-master` (I hope you're not running `react-native run-android` from within the android directory) and
2. your `local.properties` file in `BrainG-master/android` has the location of your android SDK specified in the following format: `sdk.dir=/Users/username/pathToYourAndroidSdk`.

If there is no `local.properties` file, open the project in Android Studio and it will create that for you.

If you're on Linux, you can also configure the android home environment thus:

> Add the following lines to your $HOME/.bash_profile config file:
>
> `export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk`
>
> `export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools`
>
> `export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools`
>
> `.bash_profile` is specific to `bash`. If you're using another shell, you will need to edit the appropriate shell-specific config file.
>
> Type source `$HOME/.bash_profile` to load the config into your current shell. Verify that `ANDROID_HOME` has been added to your path by running `echo $PATH`.

You can follow the instructions here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#2-install-the-android-sdk